# ImportError: cannot import name ValidatedFile

Tags: python, django

I am a new django / python developer.  I am trying to limit the type of files that can be uploaded to a certain extension.  I found the django-validated-file 2.0 app that will do this, but when I try and use it I get the following error.

"ImportError: cannot import name ValidatedFileField"

I have tried every variation of import I can find.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Here is my requirements.txt I am using python 2.7

```
Django==1.5.2
South==0.8.2
distribute==0.7.3
django-html5-boilerplate==1.0.5
django-markdown-deux==1.0.4
django-tables2==0.14.0
django-validated-file==2.0
markdown2==2.1.0
mysql-python==1.2.4
pillow==2.1.0
python-magic==0.4.3
six==1.4.1
```

Here is the part of the settings.py file.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'media',
    'south',
    'plugin',
    'PIL',
    'markdown_deux',
    'django_tables2',
    'validatedfile',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

Here is the relevant portion of my model.

```
from django.db import models
from validatedfile import ValidatedFileField
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL.Image import core

# Create your models here.

class Plugin(models.Model):
    pluginTitle = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    pluginUrl = models.TextField()
    pluginLanguage = models.ForeignKey('media.Language')
    pluginAuthor = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='pluginAuthor')
    pluginWebsite = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    pluginInstructions =  models.TextField()
    pluginFile =  ValidatedFileField(
                    null = True,
                    blank = True,
                    upload_to = 'files/',
                    max_upload_size = 52428800,
                    content_types = ['text/groovy'])
    #models.ValidatedFileField(upload_to='files/', max_upload_size=52428800, content_types = ['text/groovy'])
    pluginLogo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    pluginStatus = models.ForeignKey('plugin.Status')
    pluginType = models.ForeignKey('plugin.PluginType')
    pluginRevisionDate = models.DateField()
    pluginSourceLocation = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    pluginVersion = models.IntegerField ()
    pluginDescription =  models.TextField()
    pluginApiName = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    createdBy = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='plugin_createdBy')
    createdOn = models.DateField()
    modifiedBy = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='plugin_modifiedBy')
    modifiedOn = models.DateField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.pluginTitle
```

Here is what the developer of the file says to do.

```
from django.db import models
from validatedfile import ValidatedFileField

class TestModel(models.Model):
    the_file = ValidatedFileField(
                null = True,
                blank = True,
                upload_to = 'testfile',
                max_upload_size = 10240,
                content_types = ['image/png'])
```

Comment: Looks like validatedfile is an app. What is the name of the py file which contains the class?

Comment: the file is fields.py in the validatedfile directory of the django_validated_file-2.0-py2.7.egg directory  C:\django\serviidb\Lib\site-packages\django_validated_file-2.0-py2.7.egg\validatedfile

Comment: Then you need to import as `from validatedfile.fields import ValidatedFileField`

Comment: Added what the developer of the module says to do to the main post at the bottom.

Comment: I saw the documentation you are refering to. I guess he/she forgot to update the documentation. Just try `from validatedfile.fields import ValidatedFileField`. If that were true, he would  atleast import the class in `__init__.py` - Guess its a mistake. .

Comment: thank you that worked, I will send developer a message about the error.  thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37847/discussion-between-karthikr-and-moltra)